# How do i comment on github

Tags: github

My teacher told me to put comments on each change on my GitHub repository but I don't know how to do it. This is my first time using Github so I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: when did people stop using websearch?

Comment: @Piglet: [the September that Never Ended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) 

Answer (score 0):

What your teacher probably means is to commit each of your changes with a message that says what you have changed. I recommend to read about how git works, what commits are and how you use them.
You might find these helpful:

- https://www.atlassian.com/git
- https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners

But you can also just find your own guide.